# Using InfoPath form to show comments in version history

Tags: 2013, infopath, version

I'm using our company SharePoint 2013 and don't have access to workflows or Designer.  I'm trying to figure out how to show all list comments on version history when we do an excel export.  I created a list with a multi-line field called Notes that can append changes to text.  Then using InfoPath form I created a blank field called Blanks.  I then created a third field in Infopath called Previous Notes that is multiple lines and it concatenates the Notes and Blanks fields.  This is how I can see all notes in an export not just the most recent comment. But the Previous Notes field also grabs the Modified name and date fields which makes the column look very messy.  I can't figure out how to delete or remove the Modified name/date fields so only the comments are shown.  Is there a way to do this in Infopath?